# Extraction directory not cleaned up if clicked on Cancel on Extraction dialog

Tags: install4j

I am evaluating Install4j (version 7.0.8) and developed a tryout installer.
When it is launched, extraction dialog appears. It extracts files in temp directory.

As stated in title, if clicked on Cancel button of extraction dialog, files which were extracted, are not deleted upon cancellation.

Is there any way to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed the case and cannot be changed in install4j 7. I've created an issue for install4j 8.